# Filling listView columns with different arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, listview

Suppose I have three arrays-

```
public bool[] A = { false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true };
public bool[] B = { false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true };
public bool[] X = { false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true };
```

And an empty listView named lvTAB.
Is there a way to fill the first column in listView with the values of the first array,second and third respectively?

Comment: a foreach will do the work I suppose

Comment: and how to select first,second and third column programatically?

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=0;
foreach (bool b in A)
{
        string[] row = { b.ToString(), B[i].ToString(), X[i].ToString() };
        var listViewRow = new ListViewItem(row); 
        listView1.Items.Add(listViewRow);
        i++;
}
```